# How to apply CSS to a parent element if only a certain child element exists?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there a way to use CSS to apply styles to a parent element only if the parent has a certain child element?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="Environment">
    <div class="col-md-6 interior_environment">
        <div class="aboutEnvironment">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="title_environment"></div>
                <div class="description_environment">
                    <p><span>The natural environment or natural world encompasses all living and non-living things occurring naturally, meaning in this case not artificial. The term is most often applied to Earth or some parts of Earth.</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add the following CSS(mentioned below) to `.Environment` and `.interior_environment` only if `.aboutEnvironment` class is present inside .`Environment .interior_environment`.

If `.aboutEnvironment` class is not present inside .`Environment .interior_environment` then this CSS should not be added to `.Environment` and `.interior_environment`.

```
.Environment
{
  display: block;
}
.interior_environment
{
  flex: 1;
}
```

Is there a way to do this using CSS or does it have to be done through JavaScript?

Comment: `$(".aboutEnvironment").closest(".Environment").addClass("environment-has-about")`

Comment: @freedomn-m I am confused. Why are you adding `.environment-has-about`? How will I be able to add CSS using this code?

Comment: You say you want to "add" `.Environment` class to `.Environment` - but, *by definition* that class already *is* that class.  So you need to add a new class.  Don't be adding/changing css directly, use classes.   So you just need to define the class, and that name was a simple example that made it clear what it did.

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant I made a comment on your answer. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There are several other ways please try below one:

1. This will search for class pattern and apply the styles you need:

> ```
> div[class*="aboutEnvironment"]{
>  /* Write css style that  you want to apply  */
> }
> ```

2. This will apply and check if the class is present, however it may not be supported in firefox just check once rest other browsers have added support for this one, [refer](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

   > div:has(> aboutEnvironment){
   > >  /* Write style that  you want to apply  */ }
3. Also you can use get the element by className and then apply your classes to it.using:

> `document.getElementsByClassName("aboutEnvironment");`

4. Please try:

> .Environment > .interior_environment > .aboutEnvironment { /* Write
> style that  you want to apply  */ }

5.Also you can try [this](https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)

Comment: Can you please try  4th option

Comment: None of your answers will work. You haven't read the question properly:  ___apply CSS to a parent element if only a certain child element exists?___ All your answers target applying CSS over the child element, while OP wants to apply it over the parent element after the class hierarchy matched.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.Environment .interior_environment .aboutEnvironment').length > 0) {
        $('.Environment').css('display', 'block');
        $('.interior_environment').css('flex', '1');
    }
});
```

This a simple way to do this. You can also try the more complex way of checking each child or parent but that would be not so clean.

By using the above method, it will return false for the condition if `.aboutEnvironment` is not present inside the other two classes.

Remember this will only work if there is only one such element in the page if there are multiple such elements you need to use the child element and parent element feature of jQuery.

Comment: This only works if there's only 1 .Environment

Comment: Yes I have mentioned that in my answer that it only works for one such element.